# Google Maps Engine Layer refresh after insert

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-engine

I have a Google Maps where i've added and MapsEngineLayer (i also tried with DynamicMapsEngineLayer you can check the code for both here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/mapsenginelayers). On the website - HTML and Javascript - i have an edit button where i change, via Google Maps Engine API, some attributes of some features or add new features (geometries) to the datasource of that layer. Those inserts are made via an ajax call to php (similar to https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/documentation/feature-create).

All the authentication is made as a Service Account so the token for the layer and API is the some for 3600 seconds.

After the Insert/Update nothing appears on the map but, if i open a new private window all the modifications are there.

Wich is the best way to force the refresh of the MapsEngineLayer entirely or only the tiles affected by that insertion?

I already tried, after the insert:

```
mapsEngineLayer.unbindAll();
mapsEngineLayer.setMap(null);
mapsEngineLayer = null;
```

I can use GeoJSON to re-read all the features but the datasourcs have a lot of featues.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to force a reload of the layer without destroying the entire map:

```
layer.setMap(null);
delete layer;
layer = new google.maps.visualization.MapsEngineLayer({ layerId: ... });
layer.setMap(map);
```

This should also work for DynamicMapsEngineLayer.

Comment: Btw, that `delete layer;` statement doesn't do anything, since that only works with deleting object attributes, not variables.